# WinForms; detecting form closed from another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Is it possible to detect a form closing from another form.
For example.
If I had a mainForm that opens subForm, can I detect within the mainForm that the subForm has closed and execute code?

I understand I could create an event handler within the subForm, but this is not really what I'm after because what I'm about to do after the subForm closes, is within the mainForm (changes to mainForm).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FormClosed event is public, so you can create a handler from the main form.

```
//Inside main Form.  Click button to open new form
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Form2 f2 = new Form2();
      f2.FormClosed += F2_FormClosed;
      f2.Show();
}

private void F2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form was closed");
}
```

Comment: I feel silly now, did not know it's public so my guess would'v been making an event.

Comment: I might have done something wrong here but I can't seem to get this to work. error: cannot convert void to FormClosedEventHandler.

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo somewhere in your code.  I have been a bit more concise above, which might help.

Comment: Oh I forgot the parameters for the overloaded one...Thank you works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`public FormClosedEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx). Since the modifier is public, you're able to do something like the following example:

```
SubForm subForm = new SubForm();
subForm.FormClosed += delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("subForm has closed");
};
subForm.ShowDialog();
```

The above example creates a new form (of type SubForm), adds a new event handler to display a message box telling the user that the form has closed, and finally uses the `ShowDialog()` method which will prevent the user accessing the main form until the sub form has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The usual case for this is a "Modal Dialog" (like Message Box and its Family).
Every form can be opened as Modal Dialog, by using ShowDialog() isntead of Show().

Otherwise the event way is the only way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with dialog as he did not specify if it was. The main form might need to be interacted with while the subform is open.

Comment: As he did not specifiy this was/wasn't about a Dialogs, it could also be he was not aware that writing your own Dialog is simple. There are literally only two ways for this. I mentioned both.