# Main form with button A to open Form A and then disable button A until Form A is closed. Do the same with B

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Visual Studio project file: `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

I have a Winforms application whose main form has two buttons, button A and button B.

I have coded button A so that it disables itself when clicked, launches form A, and when form A is closed, control returns to the button click event where button A is re-enabled:

```
            btnA.Enabled = false;            
            FormA frmA = new FormA();
            btnA.Enabled = frmA.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK;
```

However this does not allow the user to do anything on the main form until frmA is closed.

When button A is clicked, I still want to disable button A so that the user cannot open another form A. But I also want the user to be able to click button B on the main form and have that logic work the same way: disable button B, launch form B, re-enable button B.

What I am trying to do is give the user the ability to launch one form A and one form B from the main form. Can I accomplish that with the pattern I've described? If so, how? (Note: There could be buttons C and D later.) I would gladly consider a different/better approach. Thanks Hedge.

Comment: `ShowDialog()` is modal.  Did you mean `Show()`

Comment: @LarsTech currently I am using ShowDialog(). I would like to use Show(), but would that lead me to writing a lot of code to accomplish what I want to do? Trying to avoid ugly coding. If I use Show(), I would need to capture the form A close event so that I would know to re-enable button A. Is that correct? If that is a better solution, how do I capture that event on the main form?

Answer (score 0):

I found a SO solution using Show() and capturing the close event on Form A:

[WinForms; detecting form closed from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203956/winforms-detecting-form-closed-from-another-form)

Not much coding involved at all.